# Parsing Get-GPOReport XML files

Tags: xml, xslt, powershell

I have created XML files with Get-GPOReport powershell cmdlets. Now I want parse files with XSLT. But I have no idea where I can found XML elements values description.

For example in XML file there is element - ClearTextPassword

```
      <q1:Name>ClearTextPassword</q1:Name>
      <q1:SettingBoolean>false</q1:SettingBoolean>
      <q1:Type>Password</q1:Type>
```

which has description - '...Store password using reversible encryption for all users in the domain...' . Where possible to find description of those XML files?

Comment: Note that 'ClearTextPassword' is not an xml element, is just text. Might be this is not an xml / xsl question?

Comment: Fernando, you are right

Comment: Kostia - did you ever get a clean way to parse these XML files?  I'm looking to do the same so I can process the data with Splunk but having no luck.